# Função sintática dos termos

Tags: untagged

Estava analisando algumas questões do concurso público da Guarda Municipal da Bahia de 2019 da banca FGV e me deparei com esta questão:

```
“Muito se tem falado de conservação do meio ambiente, mas não 
se criou ainda a consciência de que o planeta precisa 
urgentemente de nossos cuidados.” 
(Brasil Escola) 

Assinale a opção que indica os termos que, nesse segmento do 
texto, desempenham a mesma função sintática. 

(A) de conservação / do meio ambiente 
(B) de que o planeta precisa urgentemente / de nossos cuidados 
(C) de conservação / de nossos cuidados 
(D) de que o planeta precisa urgentemente de nossos cuidados / 
do meio ambiente 
(E) de conservação / de que o planeta precisa
```

Na minha opinião, seria a letra C, pois, no segmento acima: **de conservação** é objeto indireto do verbo **falar** que leva a preposição **de**, ou sintaticamente, **complemento verbal.**

**de nossos cuidados** apresenta a mesma relação sintática: objeto indireto (complemento verbal) do verbo **precisar** que leva a preposição **de**

Porém, o gabarito dizia ser letra D. Não concordo com essa resposta. Alguém poderia me explicar se minha resolução está correta, ou a banca errou?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Resposta curta**
A banca está certa em apontar a letra D como resposta.

**Resposta longa**
O problema do seu raciocínio está na incorreta identificação dos limites dos sintagmas que desempenham as funções sintáticas. A afirmação de que ***de conservação*** é *objeto indireto* do verbo ***falar*** está parcialmente correta, pois o *objeto indireto* completo desse verbo é, na verdade, ***de conservação do meio ambiente***.

A tabela abaixo apresenta os seis trechos que compõem os pares dos cinco itens da questão:

|  | Trecho | Sintagma Completo? | Função |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | de conservação | Não | Nenhuma |
| 2 | do meio ambiente | Sim | Complemento Nominal |
| 3 | de que o planeta precisa | Não | Nenhuma |
| 4 | de que o planeta precisa urgentemente | Não | Nenhuma |
| 5 | de que o planeta precisa urgentemente de nossos cuidados | Sim | Complemento Nominal |
| 6 | de nossos cuidados | Sim | Objeto Indireto |

As outras quatro letras são invalidadas pelo mesmo problema de incompletude sintagmática. A incompletude do trecho 1 ***de conservação*** invalida as letras A, C e E. Enquanto a letra B é invalidada pela incompletude do trecho 4.

A letra D está correta, pois, além de os trechos comparados serem sintagmas completos, ambos os trechos (5 e 2) são *complementos nominais* de ***conservação*** e ***consciência***, respectivamente.

É interessante notar que a questão induz o aluno a focar na comparação entre as funções sintáticas dos comparandos de cada item. Entretanto, a resolução se baseia em algo mais fundamental: o trecho exerce **alguma** função sintática ou ele só faz parte de uma cadeia maior que, ela sim, exerce função sintática na oração?

Comment: Credo, nem entendi a pergunta. :)

Comment: +1 Note apenas que, via de regra, não é necessário indicar edições feitas explicitamente (a menos que alterem a natureza da resposta), pois versões anteriores podem ser consultadas: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/9639/revisions .

Comment: Perfeita resposta e explicação.

Comment: Eu não considerava essa delimitação sintagmática ao fazer a análise dos termos, isso foi o que me fez errar a questão. 
Além disso, refiz a análise e vi que a letra (D), de fato é a correta (mesmo o meu raciocínio também estando parcialmente correto), pois, os termos apontados são de fato complementos nominais. Conferi alguns estudos e vi que Complemento nominal só pode ser aplicado a substantivos abstratos.
Obg pela explicação.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, @stafusa. Como só fiz duas contribuições até agora aos sites do Stack Exchange, não me atentei a isso. Realmente minha edição não alterou a natureza da resposta então, como as versões anteriores são consultáveis, vou deixar sem meu aviso explícito de edição.